# EOFerror in python when executing my code

Tags: python

When i run the program i'm getting EOFError...Please help

```
import sys
t=raw_input()

while(t>0):
    pa=raw_input()
    if(pa>0.500000):
        ans=10000*pa*(3-(2*pa))
        print '%0.6f' % ans
    if(pa<=0.500000):
        pa=1-pa;
        ans=10000*pa*(3-(2*pa))
        print '%0.6f' % ans    
    t=t-1
```

Comment: how are you running the file?  someone will have to add the input where `t=raw_input()`

Comment: raw_input() will return string. You need to covert it to float before doing comparisons.

Comment: @rajpy that doesn't explain the EOFError

Comment: Is it caused by your input?  What is your input?  Also, you do not have prompt message, it may help to add one so you know what the code is doing.

Comment: @Elazar: Yeah. I know. Just pointing out that he is doing wrong.

Comment: My guess is, this is not a copy-paste, and some `)` was forgotten somewhere.

Comment: @rajpy could that happen because of that bad indentation you've fixed? in some older version of python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really not giving enough input here, but you could always try this:

```
import sys

t=raw_input()
try:
    t=int(t)
except:
    sys.exit(1)

while(t>0):
    pa=raw_input()
    try:
        pa=float(pa)
    except:
        break
    if(pa>0.500000):
        ans=10000*pa*(3-(2*pa))
        print '%0.6f' % ans
    if(pa<=0.500000):
        pa=1-pa;
        ans=10000*pa*(3-(2*pa))
        print '%0.6f' % ans
    t=t-1
```